# Which is the best transferMode for soap response?

Tags: wcf, web-services

I have added service reference to my web.config file but I am not sure about the transferMode property inside binding tag.

In the basicHttpBinding, which is the best transferMode for soap/xml response?

Comment: Buffered is the one that's probably used most. You can also use Streamed, StreamedRequest and StreamedResponse.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.transfermode%28v=vs.90%29.aspx for details on these options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically there are four [transfer mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.transfermode.aspx). If you narrow down those to two, buffered and streamed, here is the criteria:

If you are transferring large files, mostly binary files, try using **streamed**. This method streams the data to the client instead of sending a big chunk of data. It helps your application to be more efficient in terms of memory consumption. Some of the advanced functionalities of WCF are not available with this transfer mode.

By default **buffered** is selected. This is suitable for normal messages with relatively small or medium size. The whole request or response will be buffered in memory and then flush to the client or server.

There is another method that needs a custom channel that send messages in multiple chunks. 
[Chunk Channel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa717050.aspx)